# Creating log records when updating users records

Tags: php, mysql, logging

I'm trying to create a `log` table that register all the events the users do on my app (create and update records).
So far I can register on the `log` table the a user who creates a record, but now I need to create a new register for the `log` table when the user update something, eg: The user Mike register a deviler of a Phone to the employee Kyle **(This is working so far)** but then the user Mike register that the employee Kyle returned that Phone. (the log should now register the update but adding a new record on `log` table.

Thanks in advance!

I have this so far:

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ativos (ativo,comentario,data_aquisicao,localizacao,fabricante,modelo,imei,
            numero_serie,ativo_sap,evento,data_evento,id_colaborador) 
            SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, id_colaborador 
            FROM colaboradores 
            WHERE nome = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($ativo,$comentario,$data_aquisicao,$localizacao,$fabricante,$modelo,$imei,$numero_serie,$ativo_sap,$evento,$data_evento,$id_colaborador));

if ($q) {
    //get last ID that was generated by previos insert
    $id_ativo = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    }
    $log  = "INSERT INTO log_ativos (acao_log,data_log,id_ativo,id_colaborador)
SELECT ?,?,?, id_colaborador
FROM colaboradores
WHERE nome = ?";
    $qlog = $pdo->prepare($log);
    $qlog->execute(array($acao_log2,$data_log2,$id_ativo,$id_colaborador));
    Database::disconnect();
```

And it's not creating a new record on `log` table when I update the main record of `ativos` table

Comment: have you researched on [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's due to trying to find a record in `colaboradores` with `nome` equal to `$id_colaborador`, if this last value is the actual ID, then insert it directly...

```
$log  = "INSERT INTO log_ativos (acao_log,data_log,id_ativo,id_colaborador)
            VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
$qlog = $pdo->prepare($log);
$qlog->execute(array($acao_log2,$data_log2,$id_ativo,$id_colaborador));
```

Comment: It gives me this :/ `Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Comment: What integrity constraints do you have on the table?

Comment: I didn't understand what are u asking